# mostrar datos de distintas tablas en un form select

Tags: php, html, mysql

tengo dos tablas:

```
version_mk             
id   version_mk        
1    mortal kombat 1   
2    mortal kombat 2   
3    mortal kombat 3   
4    mortal kombat 4   

jugador_mk
id   version_mk    luchador
1    1             liu kang
2    1             sub-zero
3    2             liu kang
4    2             sub-zero
5    4             reiko
```

y este es mi codigo:

```
<?php

include('../inc.php');

$t = mysqli_query($cnx, "SELECT * FROM juegos_mk");
$j = mysqli_query($cnx, "SELECT * FROM jugadores_mk");

?>

        <form action=".php" method ="POST">
    <p>Nombre jugador:</p>
    <select name="id">
        <option value="">Escoje peronaje</option>
            <?php

            while ($v = mysqli_fetch_array($j)) {
                echo "<option value=".$v['id'].">".$v['nombre_jugador'];
            };
                while ($mk = mysqli_fetch_array($t)) {
                    echo " - ".$mk['version_mk']."</option>";
                };
            ?>
    </select><br>
    <p>Nombre jugador: </p><input type="text" name="jugador">
    <p>Historia: </p><textarea name="historia" id="historia" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <p> imagen: </p><input type="text" name="img"><br><br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="1">cargar</button>
    </form>
```

lo que busco es que cuando despliego el select del form me aparezca el nombre del luchador con su respectiva version de mk y hasta ahora no lo estoy logrando
alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 0):

Mira esto tal vez te sirva

```
while($v = mysqli_fetch_array($j)){
   echo '<option value="'.$v['id'].'">'.$v['nombre_jugador'];
   while($mk = mysqli_fetch_array($t)){
       if($v['version_mk']==$mk['id']){
         echo $mk['version_mk'].'</option>';
       }else{
         echo '</option>';
       }
   }
}
```

Aunque yo prefiero hacerlo con un foreach, a veces los while se hacen infinitos cuando no lo sabes manejar.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda y por tu tiempo, probe ese codigo que me pasas, pero no es lo que necesito, con ese codigo el unico item que aparece completo en el select es el primero, los demas solo muestran el nombre del luchador

Comment: Trata de utilizar un foreach para correr los arrays, prueba primero a ver si te funciona imprimir los valores, luego cuando estes seguro que imprime bien los datos. agregale la maqueta html, o trata de agregar a dentro del IF el primer echo del jugador y unes con el del juego.